# Element does not being draggable after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When page loads, I'm creating some objects which are draggable. This is the code:

```js
let toolbar_items = document.getElementById('toolbar-items');
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let htmlString = `
        <div class="toolbar-item draggable ui-widget-content" id="i${items[i].item_id}_num0"> ${items[i].item_name} </div>
    `;
    let current = toolbar_items.innerHTML;
    toolbar_items.innerHTML = current + htmlString;
    if (i + 1 % 2 == 0) {
        toolbar_items.innerHTML += "<br>";
    }
};
```

And this works completely fine. But this is the issue, I'm appending another draggable item in an jQuery event. That doesn't work. I'm trying to figure it out for like couple hours but I couldn't.

This is the code of event which I'm appending new element:

```js
$(`.toolbar-item`).on( "mousedown", function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("toolbar-item-out")) return; 
    
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    let item_id = id.split('_')[0].split('i')[1];
    let item_num = id.split('_')[1].split('num')[1];
    let htmlString = `
        <div class="toolbar-item draggable ui-widget-content" id="i${items[item_id].item_id}_num${item_num + 1}"> ${items[item_id].item_name} </div>
    `;

    $(htmlString).insertBefore($(`#${id}`));

    // I created the same element (which is clicked on it) with changing the id then placed in the 
    // same position at the upper code.
    // And at the code in the down, I'm bringing the original element to my mouse position.
    // The original element is draggable so I can drag it anywhere.
    // But the new generated element doesn't able to drag.

    $(this).prependTo('.area').attr('style', 'position: fixed !important; color: red;').offset({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX }).addClass("toolbar-item-out").addClass('z-index-10')
        .on( "mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('z-index-10');
        });
});
```

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

I need help about this.

Comment: try `$(document).on( "mousedown",'.toolbar-item', function(e) {` your current event only works for those .toolbar-item that exist in the dom when the code was executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So...

This happens because scripts being loaded and when I append any element script has been already loaded so elements doesn't see the scripts.

This is how did I solved it:

First of all, at the where I create and append the new element I added 2 lines of codes:

```js
        let id = $(this).attr('id');
        let item_id = id.split('_')[0].split('i')[1];
        let item_num = id.split('_')[1].split('num')[1];
        let htmlString = `
            <div class="toolbar-item draggable ui-widget-content" id="i${items[item_id].item_id}_num${item_num + 1}"> ${items[item_id].item_name} </div>
        `;
        $(htmlString).insertBefore($(`#${id}`));

        // I ADDED THESE TWO CODES
        let new_id = `i${items[item_id].item_id}_num${item_num + 1}`;
        $(`#${new_id}`).draggable();
```

Now I can drag the new generated item. But there still a problem. When I drag the new generated item, there will not be any new item. Because -like I said- script is already loaded.

SO.

I put the whole code in a function then I called it after I append the element.

This is the final code:

```js
function reload_event() {
    $(`.toolbar-item`).on( "mousedown", function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("toolbar-item-out")) return; 
        
        let id = $(this).attr('id');
        let item_id = id.split('_')[0].split('i')[1];
        let item_num = id.split('_')[1].split('num')[1];
        let htmlString = `
            <div class="toolbar-item draggable ui-widget-content" id="i${items[item_id].item_id}_num${item_num + 1}"> ${items[item_id].item_name} </div>
        `;
        $(htmlString).insertBefore($(`#${id}`));
        let new_id = `i${items[item_id].item_id}_num${item_num + 1}`;
        $(`#${new_id}`).draggable();
    
        reload_event();
    
        $(this).prependTo('.area').attr('style', 'position: fixed !important; color: red;').offset({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX }).addClass("toolbar-item-out").addClass('z-index-10')
            .on( "mouseup", function() {
                $(this).removeClass('z-index-10');
            });
    });
}

reload_event();
```

That works perfectly fine.